# How do I alter AppName in Inno

Tags: inno-setup

Is there any way to programmatically alter the AppName in Inno Setup?  Perhaps a registry value that can be set towards the end of the installation?  My customer needs to be able to install multiple instances of my application with slightly different behaviors, and it would be ideal if AppName could be altered to during the install accomodate this (note that versioning is a separate consideration).

Comment: Why do you think altering the AppName will enable you to install multiple instances with different behaviors?  Maybe AppID is what you are after... but your question is too vague to know.  Why at the end and not at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that 'AppName' is a required scripting directive and cannot be changed after your Inno Setup script is compiled into an installer.

It seems strange that you need multiple instances of your application installed on the same machine that each behave slightly different. Why is this necessary? What does this accomplish? I'm willing to bet that this should be addressed instead of modifying your Inno Setup installation script.